# PHP server socket & webSocket HTML5 client

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

What I'm trying is connect the client [webSocket] with PHP server socket. My server socket will accept the socket from client, and fetch the Request headers.

After receiving the request, I sent back handshake [response]. But the status for webSocket [client] is pending and never gets the response.

JS code:

```
  const URL = "ws://localhost:8050";
  var socket = new WebSocket(URL);

  socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Socket is opened!");
  }
  socket.onmessage = function() {
    console.log("new message!");
  }
```

And this is my PHP server socket:

```
$this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);


    if (socket_bind($this->socket, self::ADDRESS, self::PORT) === false) {
      throw new Exception("Could not bind socket at address ${self::ADDRESS}, port ${self::PORT}");
    }


    if (socket_listen($this->socket) === false) {
      throw new Exception("Could not listen!!");
    }

    $running = true;
    $clients = [];
    while ($running) {

      if (count($clients) < 2) {
        $accept = socket_accept($this->socket);
        // handshake
        $this->handshake($accept);
        $clients[] = $accept;

        sleep(2);
        continue;
      }
    }
```

handshake function:

```
  private function handshake($client) {

    if ($client instanceof Socket || is_resource($client)) {
      echo "== Client is Vaild ==\n";
    }

    // client sent the Request
    $read = socket_read($client, 2048);
    if ($read === false) {
      throw new Exception("Could not Read!!");
    }

    // headers
    if (preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)/", $read, $matches)){ 

      $key = base64_encode(hash("sha1",$matches[1]."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")); 

      $response_header = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
      "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
      "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
      "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n";

      // send the response
      $bytes_sent = socket_write($client, $response_header, strlen($response_header));

      if ($bytes_sent === false) {
        echo "\n====== Cannot send the handshake ==========\n";
      } elseif ($bytes_sent > 0) {
        // ------- sent around 155 bytes ----------- //
        echo "\n====== handshake has been sent [". $bytes_sent ."bytes] ==========\n";
      }


    }
  }
```

After sending the response, the client still in pending status,
and the connection not opened.

Thank you.

The Request From Client:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8050
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.213058296.1602471332; __atuvc=1%7C52%2C1%7C3
Sec-WebSocket-Key: UmjWLRlhTXqM1rF6kSaVhQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

what i'm trying is sending back the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: NmQwYjVlY2VhMTQzMzUyYjFiNWMwZmU4Y2E3NmFjZTc4ZDc4N2I2Yw==
```

**UPDATE**

- I fixed the *Sec-WebSocket-Accept* key by using sha1(..., binary = true)
  before base64.
- End my response I added `\r\n` to end the header response.

Now I'm getting error:

> webSocket connection http://host:port failed.

Comment: After switching protocol, the browser open a new TCP connection at a specific port, but it seems like your server doesn't even listens there.
I'm not sure about your network configuration , but I would've suggest using NODEJS based socket solutions, than building this from scratch with PHP.
Maybe your problem is the APACHE/NGINX - that should specify specific headers prior the webSocket connection(Upgrade, and Connection)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i know about NODE js [socket.io ..etc] or using [Firebase..etc], but i want to test my level and challenge my self..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done, the problem was `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` key, it needed to be `trim(key)`